# How can I list all users who have signed up to Confluence today

Tags: sql, confluence

A list containing the user's name, display name, email address and the date the account was created in Confluence to be used for administration statistics and review of account information.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the sql-query macro. Change the date line to the time frame required.

```
{sql-query:dataSource=wiki|output=wiki|autoNumber = true|showSQL=false|noDataMessage=***** No users have signed up to the wiki in the period specified *****}
select 
       '['||cwd_user.user_name||'|~'||cwd_user.user_name||']' "User Name", 
        cwd_user.user_name "User Name", 
       '['||display_name      ||'|///dosearchsite.action?spaceSearch=false&queryString='||user_name||']' "Display Name",
       email_address "Email Address",
       date(cwd_user.created_date) as Created
from wiki.cwd_user
where date(cwd_user.created_date) > '2019-11-04' and date(cwd_user.created_date) < '2019-11-06'
```